# Как форматировать массив

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i] == null){
      c[i] = "";
    }


    c[i] += currency + " || "+prodaja + " || " + bidPrice + " || "+ 
     commercial+ "\n";
}
if (c[2] != null||(c[5]!=null)||(c[6]!=null)){



        c[2]=currency + " || "+prodaja +"  || "+ bidPrice +"  || " 
+commercial;
                }

}


for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {


  System.out.print(c[i]);
}
```

Выводит эти значения, но RUB,PLN,JPY,DKK и так дальше, не форматированы

```
USD || 28.082 -0.050 || 27.761 -0.033 || 28.0195 27.930020
EUR || 32.607 -0.090 || 31.970 -0.085 || 32.3292 32.362514
RUB || 0.436 +0.003 || 0.372 +0.004 || 0.4288 0.426210
GBP || 37.380 -0.066 || 35.676 -0.088 || 36.8098 36.946462
CHF || 28.560 -0.092 || 27.101 -0.130 || 28.2307 28.279023
PLN || 7.638 +0.015 || 7.083 +0.050 || 7.5686 7.545468
JPY || 0.251 || 0.239 +0.001 || 0.2497 0.249096
CAD || 21.950 +0.265 || 20.450 +0.800 || 21.5661 21.560636
AUD || 20.330 +0.030 || 19.500 +0.070 || 19.9768 19.923976
DKK || 4.370 || 4.100 || 4.3496 4.337615
NOK || 3.460 +0.020 || 3.280 || 3.4203 3.435584
SEK || 3.160 +0.010 || 2.970 || 3.1315 3.136966
CZK || 1.297 || 1.193 || 1.2570 1.253341
HUF || 0.104 +0.001 || 0.091 || 0.1008 0.100486
```

То есть я хочу что бы выводился масив такой(то есть что бы разделители(||) стояли один под другим :

```
USD || 28.082 -0.050 || 27.761 -0.033 || 28.0195 27.930020
EUR || 32.607 -0.090 || 31.970 -0.085 || 32.3292 32.362514
RUB || 0.436 +0.003  || 0.372 +0.004  || 0.4288 0.426210
GBP || 37.380 -0.066 || 35.676 -0.088 || 36.8098 36.946462
CHF || 28.560 -0.092 || 27.101 -0.130 || 28.2307 28.279023
PLN || 7.638 +0.015  || 7.083 +0.050  || 7.5686 7.545468
JPY || 0.251         || 0.239 +0.001  || 0.2497 0.249096
CAD || 21.950 +0.265 || 20.450 +0.800 || 21.5661 21.560636
AUD || 20.330 +0.030 || 19.500 +0.070 || 19.9768 19.923976
DKK || 4.370         || 4.100         || 4.3496 4.337615
NOK || 3.460 +0.020  || 3.280         || 3.4203 3.435584
SEK || 3.160 +0.010  || 2.970         || 3.1315 3.136966
CZK || 1.297         || 1.193         || 1.2570 1.253341
HUF || 0.104 +0.001  || 0.091         || 0.1008 0.100486
```

Подскажите как исправить,посоветуйте что нибудь

Comment: если это только желание, то может так все и оставить?

Comment: @МишаКотор было бы хорошо если б только желание, помочь можете?

Comment: думаю, надо перед выводом считать количество символов. Найти максимум. В следующей строке, если их меньше максимума, добавлять пробелы

Comment: @МишаКотор масив типа String

Comment: это же вопрос??

Comment: можно и так, а можно и char

Comment: @michael_best посчитал количество симвлов, вышло 726 в c[0], не может так быть, я паршу сайт, символов в 1 строке точно не 726

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84614/discussion-between-michael-best-and-cr7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого есть [форматирование](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

```
c[i] += String.format("%s || %-15s || %-15s || %-20s\n", currency, prodaja , bidPrice, commercial);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: И не забудьте, что в подобных случаях следует использовать моноширинные шрифты. Хотя у вас там одни цифры, но вдруг...